# Could not open IPV6 addr on web browser

Tags: browser, modem, ipv6

I have ipv6 address fe80::21f:a4ff:fe91:2e44%4. This is the address of modem/router.

I am unable to open this address in browser to view the web configuration. I am able to telnet to fe80::21f:a4ff:fe91:2e44%4, view the console UI & can do settings.

I can also open 192.168.1.1(IPv4 address of modem/router) in browser.

I tried [fe80::21f:a4ff:fe91:2e44] in all browsers like IE, Firefox & Chrome. It was not possible.

Comment: "i am getting a IPV6 address from Modem/router" fe80:: addresses are link-local, i.e. not assigned by an external source.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever device you are connecting to might not run the web configuration on IPv6 at all or at least not on it's Link-Local address. I know many of my devices, even those they have IPv6 support and are addressed, will not connect to a web configuration page.

Try doing the connection with telnet just to see if a connection can be made:

```
telnet fe80::21f:a4ff:fe91:2e44%4 80
```

I assume the network is operating correctly and that 4 is the correct interface. Try sending a ping also to make sure of that.